# can't get UDP packets form android emulator

Tags: android, udp

I've ben working on android app right now and faced problems with sending udp packets.

```
try {
    InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.19");
    int port = 6500;

    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    //socket.setBroadcast(true);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length,
            ipaddress, port);
    socket.send(packet);
    Log.d("packet send",packet.getAddress().toString() + " lenght "+ packet.getLength());
    socket.close();
    camera.startPreview();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've also add bunch of permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

After I run app on emulator it works ok but, even the `packets` are sent. I can't receive them on host machine (even `wireshark` do not see them). I tired to send it on `"10.0.0.2"` address, but it also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the packet send by the emulator, the destination address should be "10.0.2.2".
It is because android a emulator instance is like behind a virtual router and has its own address space.See[emulator networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking).
As 10.0.2.2 is the alias for 127.0.0.1 of your host machine,if you send packets to 10.0.2.2, it will be routed to 127.0.0.1 of your host machine, then you can capture them with wireshark on your host machine.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to send from localhost to the emulator. And everything I tried has not worked. Would you be able to suggest something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658867/udp-packets-not-received-in-emulator-from-localhost) please.